# Go gqlgen command not found occurs

Tags: go, graphql

I'm learning Go and GraphQL.
I was building a Go environment, but when I ran the `gqlgen init` command, I got a message in the terminal `bash: gqlgen: command not found`

When I ran the gqlgen init command, a message appeared in the terminal.

The command that was executed

```
$ mkdir with-apollo-api
$ cd with-apollo-api
$ go mod init github.com/yuuu/with-apollo-api
$ go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen
$ go get github.com/rs/cors

# Generate graph/schema.graphqls with gqlgen
$ gqlgen init
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have your gqlgen provided as an executable but as an dependecy in project.

To install executable run

```
go install github.com/99designs/gqlgen
```

It will install executable and now you can use it

```
gqlgen init
```

Comment: Depending on the way you installed Go, you might also have to make sure your $PATH includes the `bin/` directory into which `go install` puts executables.

Answer (score 0):

Guys if your `go generate` command doesnot work for graphql schema updation.

Follow these steps:

1. Add `tools.go` in your current directory & import the module

```
package tools

import (
    _ "github.com/99designs/gqlgen"
)
```

2. Then after synchronize your `go.mod` root file

```bash
go mod tidy
```

3. Now you can make changes into your schema by executing this command
   (and make sure u deleted your `schema.resolver.go` file)

```bash
go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

1. `rm -r graph gqlgen.yml go.sum` **or** just `go.sum` for existed project
2. `go mod tidy`
3. `go get -u  github.com/99designs/gqlgen`

Then run `go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen init`
its produce next output

```bash
Creating gqlgen.yml
Creating graph/schema.graphqls
Creating server.go
Generating...

Exec "go run ./server.go" to start GraphQL server
```

If you have already existed schema and gql server:
`go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate` works fine to

⚠️ DON'T FORGET ABOUT `tools.go` within your project

```golang
//go:build tools
// +build tools

package tools

import (
  _ "github.com/99designs/gqlgen"
  _ "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/introspection"
)
```